# Dynamic Semaphore creation

Tags: c#, .net, caching, mutex

I need some advice on some code in respect to caching and dynamic mutexs.

The code is roughly as below:

```cs
/* A bunch of code is removed for brevity */


private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

public async Task<TC> RetrieveValue(string code)
{
    if(_cache.TryGetValue(code, out var tc)) 
    {
        return tc;
    }      
    
    var semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1,  code);
    
    semaphore .WaitOne();    

    try
    {
        return await _cache.GetOrCreateAsync<TC>(code, entry => { return /* TC FACTORY */ });
    }
    finally 
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

So what is going on here is that RetrieveValue gets called multiple with the same `code` in a very, very short time frame (in some cases pretty much at exactly the same time with the same). But also with different codes at the same time. So pretty much very chatty all the time. 
The invocation of the TC factory can take a wee while, so to prevent TC factory from running concurrently for the same code I have added a semaphore. That in and of itself is reasonably straight forward.
The part that I need advice on is that as you can see in the code I am creating a named semaphore on the `code` because I only want to block the resource for that code i.e. each code gets its own semaphore, the idea being that if code `ABC` comes in first it doesn't block the next code `EFG` from retrieving its own value.
Is this feasible? Would this work at some scale, assuming I have say max 100 different codes? Running it locally seems to be reasonably happy. But I curious how much of a bad idea this could be, if it is?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

1 define in your class Dictionary (ConcurrentDictionary) of semaphores:

```
  private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _lockers
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
```

IMPORTANT: It is not mandatory to make dictionary of semaphores static. Depends on your application type, do you use IoC, etc... That's just the easiest way to ensure that semaphores are "global" and shared. But of course you're free here to make them "shared" in any other way (f.e. incapsulate them in some singletone service)

2 when your Api gets executed (.RetrieveValue(code)), add semaphore in this dictionary if it's absent and lock it before performing aby action:

```
public async Task<TC> RetrieveValue(string code)
{
    var locker = _lockers.GetOrAdd(code, new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1));
    await locker.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        // your code is here
    }
    finally
    {
        locker.Release();
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: try-finally needed, otherwise if exception happens - semaphore would be locked forever

---

Finally, that's absolutely reasonable question and of course you should not lock all application threads requesting something by code if codes "do not intersect". Personally I like technique above and had used it in different projects at least for concurrent file system access (in this case file path was a "key" of semaphore) and for caching purposes as in your case